# Has_and_belongs_to_many find if exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between two tables: `users` and `roles`.

When I add to the join table, how can I prevent duplicates so the same user in the same role can't be added twice (like a check to see if that row already exists). I know there is a `find` function but I don't think thats what I am looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

```
role = Role.find(params[:role_id])
user = User.find(params[:user_id])
role.users << user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `uniq: true` check on your habtm declaration will sort of help - it will ignore duplicates that are already present in your join table:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :uniq => true
end
```

If you want to keep the duplicates out of the join table in the first place, you'll either have to escalate the join table to a first-class join model (and use has_many-through instead of habtm) where you can declare `validate_uniqueness_of`, or you can stick with habtm and provide a custom validation callback:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :before_add => :validate_not_duplicate

  private

  def validate_not_duplicate(user)
    raise 'some error' if users.include? user
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, setting an error flag or returning `false` will not prevent the model from being added to the join table - you need to raise an exception of some sort.  Perhaps this will be a good incentive for some to stay away from habtm...

Comment: Thats perfect but is there a way to alert the user using a `flash` that it already exists?

Comment: @evanvee - updated with this, you'll need to catch any errors thrown to determine if this is happening.  Either that or not use habtm.